# Serverless command "offline" not found. VS Code Debugger

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have the following `launch.json` file.

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Serverless Offline",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless",
      "args": ["offline", "start", "--httpPort", "4000", "--noTimeout"],
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "runtimeExecutable": "node",
      "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "!**/node_modules/**"
      ]
    }
```

But I get the following error when I run the debugger from vs code. I do have both `serverless` and `serverless-offline` installed as a dev dependency.
Does the project structure has an impact on it. my node_modules folder is not the root folder.

And also included in the `serverless.yml` file.

> Serverless Error ---------------------------------------Serverless
> command "offline" not found. Did you mean "config"? Run "serverless
> help" for a list of all available commands.

Comment: its strange, does the project structure has an impact on it. my node_modules folder is not the root folder.

Answer (score 3):

Your `serverless.yml` file needs to be in the same folder where `node_modules` folder is located. Also, ensure you ran `npm install` and the `serverless.yml` contains the following

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

Follow the readme in https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline

Comment: serverless.yml it is in the same folder as node_modules

Answer (score 1):

Answering based on below statements,

> my node_modules folder is not the root folder.
> serverless.yml it is in the same folder as node_modules

Make sure you're running `serverless offline` or `sls offline` from the directory where the `serverless.yml` is located.

If you need to run it from outside of the directory where the `serverless.yml` is located, you can change the script which uses serverless-offline to first change the current working directory.

Ex:
`cd <path to the directory of serverless.yml> && serverless offline`

Side note: Also make sure the indentation of the `serverless.yml` is correct

Comment: can you elaborate your answer. I am running sls offline from the same directory. I did not understand `If you need to run it from outside of the directory where the serverless.yml is located...`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running `which serverless` from your command line?

Did you try running with the global serverless executable (not the one from node_modules)?